# Creating a HTML5 datalist on the fly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a datalist on they fly and attach it to an existing input element. But nothing happens (no dropdown arrow is shown)
jQuery would be acceptable, too.

```
var optionList = ["Seattle", "Las Vegas", "New York", "Salt lake City"];

function fillDataList() {
    var container = document.getElementById('my-text-box'),
    i = 0,
    len = optionList.length,
    dl = document.createElement('datalist');

    dl.id = 'dlCities';
    for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = optionList[i];
        dl.appendChild(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(dl);
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tomsx/704cxako/

(Example taken from this site: 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/07/30/quick-tip-autocomplete-using-html5-datalist-element/ )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the input element's `list` property as the id of the datalist:

```
<input id="my-text-box" list="dlCities"/>
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var optionList = ["Seattle", "Las Vegas", "New York", "Salt lake City"];

function fillDataList() {
    var container = document.getElementById('my-text-box'),
    i = 0,
    len = optionList.length,
    dl = document.createElement('datalist');

    dl.id = 'dlCities';
    for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = optionList[i];
        dl.appendChild(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(dl);
}
fillDataList();
```

```html
<input id="my-text-box" list="dlCities"/>
```

**OR:** If you do not want to modify the HTML,  you can use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the attribute in JavaScript:

```
container.setAttribute('list','dlCities');
```

```js
var optionList = ["Seattle", "Las Vegas", "New York", "Salt lake City"];

function fillDataList() {
    var container = document.getElementById('my-text-box'),
    i = 0,
    len = optionList.length,
    dl = document.createElement('datalist');
    container.setAttribute('list','dlCities'); // Set the attribute here

    dl.id = 'dlCities';
    for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = optionList[i];
        dl.appendChild(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(dl);
}
fillDataList();
```

```html
<input id="my-text-box"/>
```

Comment: I can't modify the html code (existing website). Therefore I need to add the list attribute by code. setAttribute() doesn't work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tomsx/704cxako/48/

Comment: Thanks mate. It works now. It looks like addEventListener() didn't work. I just removed it.

Comment: when the input tag is greater than 600px the option doesn't match the input width

Answer (score 3):

With only the input present when the page is loaded :

notice how I use "input.setAttribute('list','datalist')" and not "input.list = 'datalist' " directly.

```js
var datalist = document.createElement('datalist');
datalist.id = "datalist";
document.body.appendChild(datalist);
["Seattle", "Las Vegas", "New York", "Salt lake City"].forEach(function(data) {
  var option = document.createElement('option')
  option.value = data
  datalist.appendChild(option)
});
document.querySelector('#my-text-box').setAttribute('list', "datalist");
```

```html
<input id='my-text-box' />
```

Comment: Nice solution, and even shorter :)

Comment: Works great with `setAttribute`. Why it's not working with directly `input.list = 'datalist' ?

Answer (score 1):

try below solution using `jquery` on change of `input` text its appending options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val === "") return;
   var arr = ['apple','banana','google','code','microsoft'];
   var dataList = $("#searchresults");
   dataList.empty();
   if(arr.length) {
    for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) {
     var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", arr[i]);
     dataList.append(opt);
    }
   }

 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example 1</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type Something" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />
 <datalist id="searchresults"></datalist>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
    var optionList = ["Seattle", "Las Vegas", "New York", "Salt lake City"];

    function fillDataList() {

        var container = document.getElementById('my-text-box'),
        i = 0,
        len = optionList.length,
        dl = document.createElement('datalist');

        dl.id = 'dlCities';
        for (; i < len; i += 1) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = optionList[i];
            dl.appendChild(option);
        }
        container.appendChild(dl);
    }

fillDataList();
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="my-text-box" list='dlCities'>
```