# Is it possible to add a datalist to an input field if the input field was created on a button press?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very VERY new to HTML/CSS/Javascript and stackoverflow. I'm trying to teach myself some user inputs. Currently, I'm stuck trying to use datalists.

Under my head tag I have successfully created an input that uses the datalist boxlist using HTML. Yay!

However, I have no idea how to make the inputs created on the button press (i.e created in the javascript addFields function) also use the boxlist datalist.

How can I get the newly created input fields to use the boxlist datalist? Is it possible to declare the datalist in javascript, and still have it used by the new fields?

```js
        function addFields() {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            document.body.appendChild(input);
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <input name="box" list="boxlist" />
    <datalist id="boxlist">
        <option value="Item1"></option>
        <option value="Item2"></option>
        <option value="Item3"></option>
        <option value="Item4"></option>
    </datalist>
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Add input</button>
</head>
```

Comment: Don´t put any html elements in `<head>` Body is the place to put those things! And the script tag should be in `head`. You should really start with a beginner guide, we cant teach you the fundamentals here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a HTML5 datalist on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397664/creating-a-html5-datalist-on-the-fly)

Comment: Is what you want to achieve is, creating new `datalist` tag with same `options` when a button is pressed (in other words, *copy it*)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @elsololobo. Looking at some guides right now.

Comment: @deblocker thank you for the link! While it does contain the answer, Anakin made it much easier to understand. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working right, you just need to add the `list` attribute to the input you've created.

```
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("list", "boxlist");
```

*Note:*
It's better to wrap your `input` and `datalist` in a container, then append the input to the container. This way, it will be easier to manage afterwards.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Black3800/7kpqLg4z/